# Plane with a given point, a parallel line and an angle with another plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The problem states:

Find the equation of a plane $\alpha$ that has a point $A(1,1,-1)$, is parallel to the line $p$ given as $p:x+y=0$, $2x+y-2=0$ and forms a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ angle with the plane $\beta: x-4y-z-2=0$.

The way I've tried to solve it is:

First, since $A \in \alpha$, we know that the equation of the plane will look like

$$\alpha: a(x-1)+b(y-1)+c(z+1) = 0$$
where $\vec{n_{\alpha}} = (a, b, c)$ is its normal vector. Now we have to find that vector. From the fact that $\alpha \parallel p$ we know that $\vec{n_{\alpha}}$ and $\vec{p}$ must be perpendicular ($\vec{p}$ being the direction vector of the line $p$). The direction vector of the line we find by taking the cross product of normal vectors of the two planes that the line is given as:
$$\vec{p} = \vec{n_1} \times \vec{n_2}=(1,1, 0) \times(2, 1, 0) = (0,0,-1)$$
And now we have:
$$\vec{n_{\alpha}} \cdot \vec{p} = 0 $$
$$ (a, b, c) \cdot(0,0,-1) = 0 $$
$$-c = 0 \Rightarrow c = 0$$
So, for now, we only know that $\vec{n_{\alpha}} = (a, b, 0)$

From the third condition we have that

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{ \vec{n_{\alpha}} \cdot\vec{n_{\beta}} } { |\vec{n_{\alpha}}| |\vec{n_{\beta}}| }$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{(a, b, 0) \cdot(1, -4, -1)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{18}}$$

From that we get:
$$3\sqrt2\sqrt2\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = 2(a-4b)$$
$$3\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = a-4b$$
Squaring that gives us
$$8a^2-7b^2 -8ab=0$$

Dividing by $a^2$ and introducing $t = \frac{b}{a}$ we get:

$$7t^2+8t-8 = 0$$ where we find

$$\frac{b}{a} = \frac{-4 \pm 6\sqrt2}{7}$$

Since I've only been able to obtain the ratio of $a$ and $b$ does that mean that there are infinitely many planes that satisfy the given conditions? Or have I done something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ax+By+Cz=D$ is the same plane as $kAx+kBy+kCz=kD$ if $k\ne0$. So the problem is solved if the ratio of $a$ and $b$ is found.

Comment: Yeah, seconds after posting the question I'd realized that I was an idiot, since the vector is the same if scaled by a non-zero coefficient. 
Thanks anyway.